# create a table that contains atributes with values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a relationship where a Medic is a person, and Medic has 3 attributes:- a `ID`, a `paycheck`, and a `speciality`, and a person has a `name`,`age`,`gender`,`address`, and since a medic is a `person`, i want to make it

So when a medic is created with a specif `ID` it will get the `info( name,age etc )` from the `person` with that `id`.

Is there a way to do that without using `update`, but instead make it happen on table creation like saying `table Medic` has attributes `Name where Medic.name = Person.Name` if `person.id = medic.id`.

Comment: Don't copy data from one table to another. Keep it where it is. Create a view if needed.

Comment: Nope - a person does not have "age". A person has a birthdate from which you can derive the age when needed and for a specific point in time.

Comment: This is a normalization problem, and the 3rd normal form will most likely solve your problem. I'd recommend reading about the normal forms (up to the third is usually good enough) for relational databases. In a pinch, you don't want to keep redundant data in your database, it will give you consistency problems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

You would define `medics` using a foreign key reference:

```
create table medics (
    medic_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    payment ?,  -- whatever the type is
    specialty nvarchar(255),
    person_id int,
    foreign key (person_id) references persons(person_id)
);

create tabel persons (
    person_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    name nvarchar(255),  -- or whatever
    . . .   -- and so on
);
```

Then for an `insert`:

```
insert into medics (payment, specialty, person_id)
    select @payment, @specialty, p.person_id
    from persons p
    where p.name = @name;
```

Comment: i wanted to make it so that i wouldnt have to make that insert, but if i made an insert it would automaticly go grab the info from the person with the id in the medic

Comment: Grabbing info should be done at runtime by joining in a query, not by copying data.

Comment: @JoãoFolgado . . . You could do that with a view and an `insert` trigger on the view.